# The diophantine equation $a^n - 1 = (a-1)^m$.

Tags: diophantine-equations, exponential-function

Let $a,n,m$ be odd integers larger than one.
The diophantine equation $a^n - 1 = (a-1)^m$ fascinates me.

I know that Catalan's conjecture has been proven and that Pillai's conjecture has not been proven yet.

See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

However the proof of Catalan's conjecture is not so easy ( for beginners ).

SO I was wondering about easy proofs for the equation $a^n - 1 = (a-1)^m$.

I assume they exist because I think this special case of Catalan's conjecture is less difficult than the whole Conjecture.

Also - though probably a poor argument - because this equation looks familiar to me.
Maybe I have seen it , or something that resembles it - before.

I know that we can expand $(a-1)^m$ with the binomium theorem and I also know that $\dfrac{a^n-1}{a-1}$ can be reduced.
But Im not sure if that knowledge helps here.

It is not immediately clear how infinite descent or mod arithmetic helps.

because $m$ is odd we get $a^n -1 = (a-1)^m$ mod $a$.

This reduces to $-1 = (-1)^m$ mod $a$ which is Always true.

My guess is that we use mod $p^2$ for some prime $p$ but Im not sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want all $a,n,m$ be odd and greater than one, it makes it easier to prove that there's no solution.

*Hint*: Show that in general, $\gcd(\frac{a^n-1}{a-1},a-1)=\gcd(n,a-1).$

Now can you see the contradiction for $a>2?$

Comment: Actually I do not see the contradiction yet. Is this about parity ? gcd(odd,even) = odd. So what does that show ?

Comment: @mick, well $\gcd(\frac{a^n-1}{a-1},a-1)=a-1$ so $a-1|n,$ but $n$ is odd and $a-1$ is even, so this is the contradiction.

Comment: $gcd(\frac{5^3-1}{5-1},{5-1}) = gcd(\frac{124}{4},4) = gcd(31,4) = 1$ ! So saying $gcd(\frac{a^n-1}{a-1},a-1) = a-1$ seems wrong ?

Comment: @mick, No. Be careful you example has nothing to do with your original question. We have $a^n-1=(a-1)^m,$ so $\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}=(a-1)^{m-1}$ and then $\gcd(\frac{a^n-1}{a-1},a-1)=\gcd((a-1)^{m-1},a-1)=a-1.$

Comment: Oh I see. That might work. I think we can prove the cases where one or more of $a,n,m$ are even too. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the following more general result without using Catalan's Conjecture (i.e. Mihăilescu's theorem), but still using [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/v16_n4.pdf), which is difficult too, but is [provable using cyclotomic polynomials](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h517751).

More general result: The only positive integer solutions to $a^n-1=(a-1)^m$ are $(a,n,m)=(1,n,m),(2,1,m),(t,1,1),(3,2,3), n,m\ge 1, t\ge 3$.

Proof: If $a\in\{1,2\}$, then $(a,n,m)=(1,n,m),(2,1,m)$. Let $a\ge 3$.

If $n=1$, then $1=(a-1)^{m-1}$, so $(a,n,m)=(t,1,1), t\ge 3$.

If $n=2$, then $a+1=(a-1)^{m-1}$. If $m\in\{1,2\}$, then no solutions. If $m\ge 3$, then $a+1\ge (a-1)^2=a^2-2a+1$, i.e. $3a\ge a^2$, so $a=3$, so $(a,n,m)=(3,2,3)$.

If $a,n\ge 3$, then by [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/v16_n4.pdf) $a^n-1$ has a prime divisor that does not divide $a-1$, contradiction.